# Message Box on review queue

Tags: discussion, bug, review, user-interface

After recent changes on StackOverflow:

I found an overlapped message-box randomly on edit-suggestion queue.(I am using firefox)

[image: queue message box]

Comment: I saw it also sometimes, but it's randomly, how you said. I don't think that it can be reproduced...